# Ubuntu Touch Basque locale

Tags: ubuntu-touch, locale

How can I help to improve the ubuntu touch basque (eu_ES) locale? The localization is good but far from complete, and there is no spell checker and word proposal. I have access to basque language resources and want to help.

Answer (score 0):

Get in touch with the [Ubuntu Basque Translators team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-eu).